# Add object with basic background-color then change it to other color with delay

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an ul. With javascript I add the li's to it. I need the added li with background-color #E4F3D6 then 10 seconds later change to #DDD as final color.

I know this is possible with animation and transition-delay but I don't figure out how.

I wrote this but doesn't work properly:

```
@-webkit-keyframes change-color {
    0% {
        background-color: #E4F3D6;
        /*-webkit-transition-delay: 5s;*/
    }
    100% { background-color: transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes change-color {
    0% {
        background-color: #E4F3D6;
        /*-moz-transition-delay: 5s;*/
    }
    100% { background-color: transparent; }
}
@keyframes change-color {
    0% {
        background-color: #E4F3D6;
        /*transition-delay: 5s;*/
    }
    100% { background-color: transparent; }
}

.test {
    height: 25px;
    background-color: #E4F3D6;
    -webkit-animation: change-color 2s ease;
    -moz-animation: change-color 2s ease;
    animation: change-color 2s ease;
}
```

Here a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/junihh/a657pd6q/4/

Anyone help me, please.

Comment: If you want the final colour to be `#DDD`, why are you setting it as `transparent`?

Comment: @DavidThomas if you read the fiddle maybe you can figure out. The li has the #DDD color and the contained div have the .test class with #E4F3D6 color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `transition-delay` property in the CSS for the element itself:

```
.test {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #E4F3D6;
  -webkit-animation: change-color 2s ease 5s forwards;
  -moz-animation: change-color 2s ease 5s forwards;
  animation: change-color 2s ease 5s forwards;
}
```

The above uses the shorthand alternative for the `animation` property:

```
animation: <animation-name> <animation-duration> <animation-type> <animation-duration> <animation-fill-mode>
```

The `animation-delay` property does precisely what its name suggests, it delays the start of the animation by the value specified (here `5s`, five seconds); the `animation-fill-mode` property causes the final values of the animation to persist once the animation has completed:

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = '<div class="test"></div>';
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(li);
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
}
#container li {
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#container li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.button-box {
  margin: 20px auto 0;
  width: 100px;
}
#add {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFF;
}
#add:active {
  background-color: #333;
}
@-webkit-keyframes change-color {
  0% {
    background-color: #E4F3D6;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #F90;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes change-color {
  0% {
    background-color: #E4F3D6;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #F90;
  }
}
@keyframes change-color {
  0% {
    background-color: #E4F3D6;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #F90;
  }
}
.test {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #E4F3D6;
  -webkit-animation: change-color 2s ease 5s forwards;
  -moz-animation: change-color 2s ease 5s forwards;
  animation: change-color 2s ease 5s forwards;
}
```

```html
<ul id="container">
  <!-- li's -->
</ul>

<div class="button-box">
  <button type="button" id="add">Add row</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a657pd6q/7/).

Note that, in the demo, I've used a final colour of `#f90` instead of `#ddd` simply to make the animation more obvious (the difference between the start and end colours, otherwise, are easy to miss).